# Convert JSON values to number when key/values are dynamic

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm using d3.json to decode a dataset where the key/values are unknown.  I need to convert the number values to numbers and leave the rest alone.

My JSON looks like this:

```
[{"file":"morning","row_total":"1095935","attr1":"79","attr2":""},
{"file":"noon","row_total":"221167","attr1":"174","attr2":"114"},
{"file":"night","row_total":"1317102","attr1":"253","attr2":"114"}]
```

It's read in from a PHP file with d3.json.  For each value that can (without throwing NaN), I need to convert to a number (d3 uses the + symbol for this):

```
d3.json("getData.php", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        if(!isNaN(d.i = +d.i)
          d.i = +d.i
          )})
```

Obviously there's an issue with my testing/looping logic.  I would really appreciate some guidance here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isNaN` will work on number strings - the assignment operator is probably throwing your code off - you can just do:

```
if(!isNaN(d.i)) {
```

You're also missing a second `)` on your `if` statement with the `isNaN` check.

```
isNaN("1") //false
isNaN("x") //true
```

Suppose I should've read more. You need 2 loops - one to loop your array, the other to test the each key/val of the object your looping:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var key in data[i]) {
        if (!isNaN(data[i][key])) {
            data[i][key] = +data[i][key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tymeJV,  thank you for the tip. I'm not quite there yet...the data is not getting transformed.  Here's what I changed my code to, on your suggestion:    data.forEach( function(d) {  if(!isNaN(d)) {d = +d}  } );

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much!  This is a great model from which I can finally understand the appropriate logic. Much appreciated.